# Socket.io bad request with response {"code":0,"message":"Transport unknown"}?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, http-status-code-400

I'm trying to run socket.io and I'm getting a bunch of these:

```
http://domain.com:8080/socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1401421022966-0 400 (Bad Request)
```

This is the response I'm getting:

```
{"code":0,"message":"Transport unknown"}
```

I can't find any reason. I read somewhere that it might be misinterpreting the client, but that's about as far as I could get.

Comment: It seems like your url is not well formed. Does taking out the slash after socket.io improve your situation? Sooo, it would look like `http://domain.com:8080/socket.io?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1401421022966-0`

Comment: From socket.io's doc, here are socket.io default transports: websocket, htmlfile, xhr-polling, jsonp-polling

Comment: @grobot There is nothing malformed about that URL.  Slashes are quite common in URL's, even at the end.

Answer (score 20):

I had the same issue after upgrading from 0.9.x to 1.x.x. Shortening the long story, I would set transports to ['websocket', 'polling'] and then the error...

when you config your server to use specefic transpors you should set the same config on client side to...

server

```
    var io = require('socket.io')(server, {'transports': ['websocket', 'polling']});
```

client

```
    var io = io( serverUri, {'transports': ['websocket', 'polling']});
```

Comment: Where are these files?

Comment: i know this is late, in 2021, but let me thank you. I looked everywhere, and everybody was always solving problems by having matching versions of client and server which I already had. In my case, as soon as i blocked the transport to websocket on the server, i got the bad request error, because client was still trying to use polling! declaring transport on client as well did it! Thanks again!

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue,after upgrading from 0.9.x, turns out my server config was set to `['websocket', 'jsonp-polling']` which was valid in 0.9 but the default config for the client and server is now `['polling', 'websocket']`. 
Removing my server config got me up and running.

The config is now documented in engine.io (https://github.com/automattic/engine.io), the new transport layer introduced in 1.0 - in particular this line:
`transports ( String): transports to allow connections to (['polling', 'websocket'])`

Comment: Can you enlighten me on where the server config is? I just completely uninstalled the socket.io folder in node_modules and reinstalled and I'm still getting this problem.

Comment: This fixed it!  Fantastic.  @RiverTam The config would be in your code somewhere.

Comment: Where is this config file?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/g3ekl8 chat is working fine but the newrelic logs this.I also found all logs are from Windows NT 6.1 which may be try to connect using polling any suggestion

Answer (score 4):

i had the same issue:

Getting the latest socket-client.js and using these file on clientside, solved this problem for me.

Comment: Using the latest client javascript file fixed this problem for me too: https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.5.js

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me when I served the socket.io.js script myself.
I had to go copy `node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.js` to where I was serving it up.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: This was a while ago, but if I remember right
If my page loads on foo.com, but I am connecting to a websocket on bar.com, I had to copy the socket.io.js file onto foo.com and load it from there. I don't know if that solution will still work, or if it's the best way to do it.

Comment: Solved my problem! I used an old version in which I loaded a local version instead of directly from the node instance

Answer (score 2):

Try this configuration on **server side**:

```
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "http://localhost:8100",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"],
        credentials: true
    },
    transports: ['websocket', 'polling'],
    allowEIO3: true
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I had missing `allowEIO3: true`

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to upgrade node.js to latest (0.12.0 at the time of this post). Originally node.js was installed as a part of a bundle. Once I uninstalled that node.js coming from that bundle (Aptana 3 bundle, node.js was somewhat behind), and installed the latest from node.js's website, things started working finally.

I was experimenting with React.js. I spent several hours debugging the phenomena, I've found build errors in socket.io, specifically about socket.io-client, it tried to invoke Visual Studio MSBuild unsuccesfully. Which is sad, the error occured with node-gyp too. Apparently socket.io-client is not needed to run/serve my examples, and seems like these unfortunate errors (which lured me into an endless forest) can be ignored.

(I noticed also a module while installing webpack-dev-server, which is Darwin only (a.k.a. Mac OS X). That's fortunately an optional dependency. It's frightening though: I know that Apple is very hipster, but the majority of the world is non Mac.)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it acting in my server.js

the io instance is initialized as follow:

`const io = socket.listen(httpServer, { serveClient: true })`

Before I had `{ serveClient: false }`, because otherwise, I was getting an error. But actually, if you want that your client takes io from the node instance you have to serve it.

UPDATE: At the end.. you want to simply have const io = socket.listen(httpServer)
In this way is going to be true by default.